# QT for Android , Debug vs Release mode

Tags: android, qt

I have an mobile app written using Qt. If I deploy the app in release mode, my program is locked somowhere.

However, if I deploy in debug mode, the program works well.

I haven't found any solution. Is there a configuration for that?

Comment: Can you be more clear? What problems are you experiencing? Is there an error message?

Comment: @vic3685 , There is no error messages. I have 5 param tables in sqlite.In Debug mode , there parameters is loaded well then pass the next process.In Release mode , there parameters is loaded well but not pass next process.Busyloaders is still on page...